# Apple OSX - Prevent second partition asking for FileVault Password

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, mount, filevault

wonder if anyone can help...

So my work provides me with a MacBook Pro, what I have done is created a second partition with a second installation of OSX for personal use when at home. Both partitions are encrypted using FileVault.

What I would like to do is prevent the second partition asking for the password to mount the disk when I boot the work OSX and login.

Ideally I would like the second partition to not show at all in the built in Disk Utility.

I did try preventing the partition from mounting at all using the fstab, but that doesn't work as the disk is not mounted regardless without a password as it is encrypted.

Cheers =D